# Car brake pedal pushes against my foot

Tags: toyota, brakes, rav4

I have a 5 year-old Toyota Rav 4. There seems to be a problem with the brakes. When I press the brake pedal, it pushes my feet back in intervals, thus makes my car braking distance longer than usual. I remember seeing this problem on Youtube but forgot what it is exactly.

What is causing this problem?

Comment: sounds like the ABS might be the cause of this,any error codes or warning lights?

Comment: Two issues come to mind here.  First, as noted already, your ABS system is malfunctioning and activating when it's not needed.  Often this is caused by a defective wheel speed sensor.  Second, is a mechanical issue with your brakes such as a warped rotor.